# How to build a Go app that can cross-macOS-version?

Tags: macos, go, macos-catalina, macos-big-sur

Here is my recently created macOS app: https://github.com/evillt/macmineable-release
and here is my facing issue: https://github.com/evillt/macmineable-release/issues/18

I built the app on my machine it can run normally on any BigSur device, even M1 devices, but can not run on Catalina(10.15).

**So what I want is to build a version that can run on multi-macOS-version with a single app.**

Huge thanks for any suggestions!

#### update

My device is MacBook Pro 2015, Intel I5 chip, Big Sur 11.5.2.

I build this app on my device, it can run normally on:

- My device
- MacBook 12-inch Big Sur 11.0
- Other M1 devices (Big Sur 11.0 or above)

**But can not run on MacBook Pro Intel I7 Catalina 10.15.7. The issue [here](https://github.com/evillt/macmineable-release/issues/18).**

That is all I know.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `CC` compile go uses during your builds.

```
 go env CC

 clang
```

which most likely uses the version in `/usr/bin/clang`

if you have Xcode installed - or really just the `Command Line Tools` you can see a variety of versions for the last few major releases e.g.:

```
$ find  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools -name clang

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/swift/clang
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUCompiler.framework/Versions/A/lib/clang
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/lib/clang
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUCompiler.framework/Versions/A/lib/clang
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/lib/clang
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUCompiler.framework/Versions/A/lib/clang
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/lib/clang
```

so to build against an older SDK like `MaxOSX10.15`, set `CC` to the explicit version you need for your `go build` like so:

```
CC=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/lib/clang go build
```

Comment: Thanks but I got *permission denied*:

`cgo: C compiler "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/lib/clang" not found: exec: "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/lib/clang": permission denied`

Comment: The error shows the binary is missing. Did you run the `find` command? It will show what alternative `clang` binaries are available. You also need to ensure you have the developer command line tools installed (an option available from with the `Xcode` IDE).

Comment: Yes, I have `command line tools` installed. Run `find` has similar output.

Comment: Try running the `clang` tool directly. Permission denied error suggests it's permission bits are not set to "executable" or maybe an intermediate path is not accessible from your user account?

Comment: run `clang` with `error: no input files` . I am new to Go so I do not know what the problem actually is.

Comment: This is not a `Go` issue per se. You mentioned in your question`M1` are you running this on an `M1` device? P.S. when I said to run `clang` - did you run the one in the `MacOSX10.15.sdk`  - not just the one in the path?

Comment: I updated my question content. I got permission denied with this command. `CC=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/lib/clang go build
`

Answer (score 0):

I have good experience building as a Unix executable and packaging as a Mac app, by using the instructions manual at
https://medium.com/@mattholt/packaging-a-go-application-for-macos-f7084b00f6b5

```
build Unix exec file
go build -o bin/{program} {program}
```

Packaging the application on macOS (Big Sur) and installing it on macOS (High Sierra) was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one after another

1. go env -w CC=clang
2. go env -w GO111MODULE=off
3. go build